# Area of $\{(x,y)^T\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2<r^2 \wedge -|x|<y<|x|\}$

Tags: calculus, area

What is the area of $\{(x,y)^T\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2<r^2 \wedge -|x|<y<|x|\}$?

I have that $x\in[0,r)$ but what about $y$. There I have two restrictions.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture?

Comment: Is it maybe $y^2<r^2-x^2$ and $y^2<x^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $-\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}<x<\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$ and therefore $\lambda_2(\{...\})=\int_{[0,r)}\int_{(-\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}})}1 d\lambda(x)d\lambda(y)=\sqrt{2}r^2$

Comment: As Integrand just said, a picture should help you. Try to figure which geometric areas are delimitted by the two equations, and you should get your answer.

Comment: If $x>0$, $-x<y<x$, etc., so the figure consists of two sectors of a circle.

Comment: Ok I have the picture in front of me and I see that it is a pretty easy area but I still can´t figure out how to restrict $y$ so that I can integrate.

Comment: Is the area equivalent to the area of a half circle?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all x is not in [0,r] but in [-r,r].You will have to see x in 4 cases.
i)$x\in [-r,-r/\sqrt 2]$ then $y^2<r^2-x^2$
ii)$x\in [-r/\sqrt 2),0]$ then x<y<-x
iii)$x\in [0,r/\sqrt 2),]$ then -x<y<x
iv)$x\in [r/\sqrt 2),r]$ then $y^2<r^2-x^2$

[image: Your area]